# Q: Gmail API: How to convert com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message into javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage

Tags: gmail-api

We are looking for a utility function (in java or any other language) which can convert JSON payload returned using format=full (and which generates com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message) into  javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.

Comment: what have you tried? can you show why deserialising the properties of the object into another object isn't good enough?